# Java reads old timezone entry of linux

Tags: java, linux, timezone

I have a java application which has a two node cluster. My goal here is to make sure that all the nodes of the cluster are in same time zone.

```
TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
String slaveTimeZone = tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

The code reads the timezone correctly for the first time, say IST. Now I go and change the symlink, to point localtime to CST, but the java application doesn't pick up the updated timezone unless I restart my application.

Am I doing it correctly? Or am I missing out a step?

Comment: What symlink to which file/directory do you change?

Comment: By the way, `TimeZone` has been replaced by `ZoneId` & `ZoneOffset` classes, as of the adoption of JSR-310. To get the JVM’s current default time zone: `ZoneId.systemDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is still accessing the directory it might not recognize that there is a new directory with the same name.

A simple example for the Linux shell

**session 1**
    cd ~/tmp
    mkdir data
    cd data
    echo foo > bar
    cat bar

**output in session 1**

```
foo
```

**session 2**

```
cd ~/tmp
mv data/ data.old
mkdir data
cd data
echo baz > bar
```

**output session 2**

```
baz
```

**back to session 1, we are still in directory ~/tmp/data**

```
cat bar
```

**output session 1**

```
foo
```

Reason is. As long your application uses the original `data`directory it sees only the inodes of the original `data` directory. Changes in the new `data` directory will become visible for your application (in session 1) only after it leaves (his) `data` directory.